# Google PageRank: Does it count per domain or per webpage

Tags: pagerank

Is the Google PageRank calculated as one value for a whole website (domain) or is it computed for every single webpage?

Comment: This would have been one more opportunity for you to google before asking.

Comment: I realise that sometimes a Title does not signify its meaning, but in respect to Google PageRank, and not to ssound condescending, I feel the name is a very descriptive clue as to its purpose.  I.e. it is not called Google SiteRank. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much Google follows publicly known PageRank algorithm is their trade secret. In generic algorithm page rank is calculated per *document*.

Edit: original, generic PageRank explained http://www.ams.org/featurecolumn/archive/pagerank.html

Answer (score 3):

Google **Page**Rank

Here is a snippet and the link to an explanation from Google Themselves:

http://www.google.com/corporate/tech.html

> PageRank Technology: PageRank reflects
>   our view of the importance of web
>   pages by considering more than 500
>   million variables and 2 billion terms.
>   Pages that we believe are important
>   pages receive a higher PageRank and
>   are more likely to appear at the top
>   of the search results.
>
> PageRank also considers the importance
>   of each page that casts a vote, as
>   votes from some pages are considered
>   to have greater value, thus giving the
>   linked page greater value. We have
>   always taken a pragmatic approach to
>   help improve search quality and create
>   useful products, and our technology
>   uses the collective intelligence of
>   the web to determine a page's
>   importance.

Answer (score 2):

per webpage.

Answer (score 0):

It should be per web page.